# Colorbrewer scale only returning lightest values on D3 map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, colorbrewer

Im trying to use a colorbrewer scale on a D3 map, and for some reason it's only returning the lightest values, which is making the map look very washed out.  I'm not sure what the problem is.  Thoughts?

This is how I'm using the scale:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(colorbrewer.OrRd[8])
    .domain([0, 16000]);
```

Here's a link to the map if you want to take a look:

http://www.pitt.edu/~kac232/PittsburghMap/map_yuji.html

Much appreciation in advance.

Comment: You probably want an ordinal scale here.

Comment: I don't think so.  I thought ordinal scales were more for categorical data.  When I use an ordinal scale, some of the data is inappropriately encoded (some of the neighborhoods with higher population are actually lighter than neighborhoods with lower populations, but not consistently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `d3.scale.quantize()` to transform a continuous domain into a discrete range; you're going from a number to a particular color that matches. A linear scale assumes a continuous range. Read some more about [quantize in the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#quantize) or see [an example in action](http://eyeseast.github.io/visible-data/2013/08/27/responsive-legends-with-d3/).

The appropriate way to do what you want would be:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
    .range(colobrewer.OrRd[8])
    .domain([0, 16000]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish I knew *how* this worked, but I only know *why* it worked.  I wound up just specifying three hex values instead of using colorbrewer and for the domain I used 0, 8000, 16000.  D3 took care of the rest.